# How to cache the JS files from innerHTML of/from Ajax()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

Is there any possibility to cache the JS file that has been echo by PHP script to innerHTML or $('#id').html(data) of element such as DIV?? Do it automatically save to visitor's cache after the script source (js file) is outputted to element like  ??

The script source attribute (js file / external) that can see in the view page source can be saved to visitor's cache..
But the script source that cannot be see in page source because it requires AJAX response,  something like, it does not save to visitor's cache. (please see my codes/script below later).

I've tried multiple times in multiple ways, changing the JS file content, changing the value from inside alert(), I based on alert(), then refreshing the page to see what the alert message will come out, whatever I put in the alert(), it shows the exact value in the page, like there is no cache save..

I am using Google Chrome browser, I've found a ChromeCacheViewer, and I see that there are `http://my_host.com/SendCoins.js?_=13digits_here` with different digits.. Whenever I click the same `<a onclick="FUNCTION(showpage)">`, then another cache file in the cache history will be added `http://my_host.com/SendCoins.js?_=another13digits`).. From the cache list, the filename is the 13 digits.
See the IMAGE: http://goo.gl/NEpvR9

A cache is a mechanism for temporarily storing (caching) documents or data, to reduce access time.

Is there a possibility? If there is, how?

Sorry I can't explain clearly and well or I can't explain understandable, but I can provide example of what I am explaining.

Like for example
AJAX: (page.js)

```
 function GoToPage(Page_Post)
  var form_data = {
   Page: Page_Post
  };
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "PAGE.php",
   data: form_data,
   success: function(data)
   {
    $('#PAGE').html(data); // innerHTML
   }
  });
 }
```

AJAX: (sendcoins.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("form#sendcoins").submit(function() {
  alert("Change this whenever you/visitor have used the GoToPage() and submitted the form"); //We will base on alert if it is really save to cache.
  var form_data = {
   Coins: $('#Coins').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "SendCoins.php",
   data: form_data,
   success: function(data)
   {
    $('#message').html(data); // innerHTML
   }
  });
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="GoToPage('SendCoins')">Send Coins</a>
<div id=PAGE></div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$Page = $_POST[Page];
if( $Page == 'SendCoins' ){
 ......blah.....
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SendCoins.js"></script>';
 echo '<img src="images/coin.png">';
 echo '<form id="sendcoins" onsubmit="return false" >
  <input type=number id=Coins> <input> submit .. blah.. blah..
 </form>';
}
?>
```

So, after the source files that has been echo to innerHTML, it will be saved to visitor's cache.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the cache parameter in your ajax call. By default the cache property is set to false, and that is why your are seeing these digits in your requests.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SendCoins.php",
    data: form_data,
    cache: true, 
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#message').html(data); // innerHTML
    }
});
```

For more info on the cache property, you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Have you view this image?? http://goo.gl/NEpvR9
That's what I mean, an example of cache file that has been saved to visitor's cache.

Comment: Adding different digits in the end of the URL of each request makes each request different, thus avoiding the browser's cache. If you set cache:true, no digits will be added

Comment: Still the same @codingstill, even I add cache:true. Look at this image: http://goo.gl/Znh8wq I've added cache:true to PAGE2.js and acc_bounty.js but still the same, the acc_bounty has a random 13 digits in the end of URL that can be seen in the cache history/ChromeCacheViewer. The acc_bounty.JS can only be outputted to the page when the PAGE2.js's ajax responded. I used the PAGE2.js for <a> tag like <a onclick="GoToPage(pg)">, so whenever I click that to call for the function, another acc_bounty.js cache will be saved.. By the way, I didn't add any digits in the end of script source url

Comment: Your code shows ajax calls of .php files. In your screenshot you show me the issue with .js file. How do you load your .js file?

Comment: acc_bounty.js load after calling the function GoToPage() .. Function GoToPage() is in the PAGE2.js ....
<script src="js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js"></script><form>..etc will be outputted in the <DIV id="PAGE"> every clicking the <a onclick="GotoPage('bounty')">, so, whenever I click that <a>, it add another cache js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js_=Random?_13_digits

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are not calling "js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js" directly with jQuery.ajax(...) but you are calling page.php and this one has the HTML with the "js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js", right? If this is the case, the call "js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js" is made from the browser and not from jQuery.

Comment: OK thank you. So, there is no possibility to be saved in cache as the original source URL if the JS file is loaded in the browser?? Because it really save with 13 digits in the last of URL. Yes, js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js is in the page.php ..

Comment: You could have the js/w/usercp/acc_bounty.js in the original HTML page. If you want to load in with Ajax, take a look in the jQuery.getScript(...) function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, I will do everything just to experience something. ^_^